# Select options are loaded and disapear after

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm trying to dynamically load partial view with a different model instances inside of main view. Everything is working fine, until I have to reload partial view content. Then I have to reload 1 select list options, that is not in model. I have js method for that. Problem is, sometimes options are added, and disapear instantly. What am I doing wrong?
There are no any methods, that are changind this select control.

Main view:

```
<div id="tableContainer">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("_TableView", Model.Tables[0]);}
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadTable () {
        var selectedElement = $("#tableSelect").children("option:selected").val();
        $("#tableContainer").load("/Home/UpdateTable/" + selectedElement);
        getDishes();
    };

    window.onload = function () {
        getDishes();
    };

</script>
```

getDishes function:

```
function getDishes() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/GetDishes",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    fillDishList(result.message);
                }
                else
                    alert("Błąd podczas pobierania dostępnych dań! Treść błędu: " + result.message);
            }
        })
    }
```

And fillDishList function:

```
function fillDishList(list) {
        for (var a = 0; a < list.length; a++) {
            var element = { val: a, text: list[a].Name };
            $("#dishes").append($("<option>").attr('value', element.val).text(element.text));
        }

        updateDishPrice();
    }
```

**EDIT**
Ok I got it working. There was timing issue. Function that should append elements to select list were launched before partial view were completely loaded. Here is solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function loadTable () {
        var selectedElement = $("#tableSelect").children("option:selected").val();
        $("#tableContainer").html("");
        $("#tableContainer").load("/Home/UpdateTable/" + selectedElement);
        window.requestAnimationFrame(ready);
    };

    var ready = function () {
        var dishes = $("#dishes");
        if (dishes) {
            getDishes();
            if (dishes.children().length != 0)
                return;
        };

        window.requestAnimationFrame(ready);
    };

    window.onload = function () {
        getDishes();
    };

</script>
```

Comment: what do you mean by "reload partial view content"?  If the bug happens in a seemingly random way, I'd suspect a timing issue... possibly some page load or js update that you're not expecting to happen... so js/page load conflict or js/js async conflict.

Comment: Actually I found the bug meantime. When I'm loading new instance of _TableView and replacing old one in div "tableContainer" sometimes timing is not right. getDishes function runs before _TableView is fully loaded. In that case function runs with no problems, but appending childs to dishes list is not working. I think, that select control is defined, but not existing at the time, so I can call it, but nothing can be added.
I'm completely new in js, so I can be wrong, but when I added 20ms timeout between loading view content and calling getDishes, problem disapeared.